# How to parse a key value nested in another key whose name is not know in python?

Tags: json, parsing, python-3.x

I'd like to access the value of extract key that is nested in the pages key

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "normalized": [
            {
                "from": "sample",
                "to": "Sample"
            }
        ],
        "pages": {
            "23895873": {
                "pageid": 23895873,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Sample",
                "extract": "<p><b>Sample</b> or <b>samples</b> may refer to:</p>\n<p></p>\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a wikipedia bot that will print the summary (value of the key `"extract"`) . But the problem is that the `"pageid"` value keeps on changing with the search result . How can I do this?

I tried using json:

```
import json
import requests
wikiReq = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&titles=sample&format=json")
jsonResult = wikiReq.json()
result = jsonResult["query"]["pages"][""]["extract"]
print(json.dumps(result , indent = 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
for i in jsonResult["query"]["pages"]:
    result = jsonResult["query"]["pages"][i]["extract"]
```

Assuming there is just one item in there it will always work